# when copper oxide is dissolved in vinegar does it release copper oxide gas

Tags: toxicity

i was cleaning my pennies in a bowl of vinegar and table salt and was wondering when the copper oxide on the pennies dissolves does it release copper oxide gas or a gas i should be worried about. I was sitting outside with a fan on above me but i was worried that when i leaned over the bowl i might have inhaled somthing harmful. I tried to look up what happens but i could not find anything that states what happens to the copper oxide when its "dissolved".

Comment: Nothing to worry about: there is no “copper oxide gas”.

Comment: You're healthy enough to have posted about it here. Carry on...

Comment: I wish this degree of encouragement is also given to other new posters by moderators :-)

Comment: Thank you all i was just a little paraniod there was some sort of harmful gas

Answer (score 4):

The best defence against the fear of unknown is obtaining knowledge about it. If you studied basics of copper chemistry, you would realize that copper oxide is not a gas and that there is no easy way to obtain a volatile copper compound.

The only potentially dangerous gas there is vapor of acetic acid, natural and essential part of vinegar, with low enough concentration to be safe(*).

Insoluble solid copper oxide (possibly together with basic copper carbonates) gets transformed to blue solution of non volatile copper acetate.

$$\ce{CuO(s) + 2 CH3COOH(aq) -> (CH3COO)2Cu(aq) + H2O(l)}$$

$$\ce{CuCO3.Cu(OH)2(s) + 4 CH3COOH(aq) -> 2 (CH3COO)2Cu(aq) + 3 H2O(l) + CO2(g)}$$

---

(*) If you ever sniffed vapor over pure acetic acid, the perception would be very unpleasant and your nasal mucous membrane would be for some time very unhappy.